# Retransmission timeout reached on transmission

Tags: sip, asterisk, nat

I am configure the user account using sip and extensions configuration files.
and configure this account to mobile and i got online status.

But when i am trying to forward the call that time i got "Retransmission timeout reached on transmission"
if any one know about that. please share with me...
I have put the details on this link:

http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=88003&p=191890&hilit=retransmission#p191890

**Sip.conf:**

```
[10000]
type = friend
sendrpid=yes
context=test
username= 10000
host=dynamic
mailbox = 10000
dtmfmode = rfc2833
secret=user
nat=no
directmedia=yes
qualify=yes
disallow =all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
callerid=10000 <10000>
canreinvite=no
```

**extensions.conf:**

```
[test]
include => demo
include => test1
exten => _1000X,1,Answer
exten => _1000X,2,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten => _1000x,3,Noop()
```

[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I recomend do following:

1) Read this link article:
https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-sip-nat-solutions/

2) Determine what type you have, put settings acordinly.

3) Check your router, disable sipalg on router if enable

4) If not help, enable sip debug and put here output of sip debug and network scheme,including devices model.

Comment: i have updated my question.please you have look on that and how to check router, disable sipalg on router if enable?

Comment: and i am using ubuntu server

Comment: i think you have NAT. So you need say asterisk you have it and configure asterisk - see link above.